# trap user signal and continue executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
trap 'echo yo2 > $fifo' USR1

out(){ while read -r line; do echo $line; done; }

fifo=~/fifo
[ -e $fifo ] && rm $fifo
mkfifo fifo

tail -f > $fifo &
while :; do
    echo yo1 > $fifo
    sleep 1
done &

out < $fifo
```

I am trying to trap USR1 signal in order to echo into the FIFO I have kept open in my script but after receiving the signal, the FIFO is closed and the script, terminated.

Comment: You probably want to include more detail, like minimal script to reproduce the behavior. I've tried and with `trap f SIGUSR1` it calls `f()` on SIGUSR1 and then resumes... perhaps your handler contains `exit`?

Comment: The function just echos into the FIFO I have kept open using the script.
First I thought it's due to the echoing into the FIFO but after further testing, I can assure you no matter what I do in the function, the FIFO gets closed & the script gets terminated after the signal.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Just updated my question with the a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

When the shell handles a signal with `trap`, any currently pending `read` will fail.  That is why the script terminates prematurely.

To fix this, set a flag in the handler.  Then when `read` fails, check the flag.  If the flag is set, then you know `read` failed because of the signal rather than end of file, so you should continue executing the loop.

### What is happening?

First, let's simplify the script somewhat and also add some printouts to see what's going on.  Here is `trap-fifo1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "my PID: $$"

trap handler USR1

handler() {
  echo "in 'handler'"
  echo caught_user1 > fifo
  echo "handler complete"
}

out() {
  echo "in 'out'"
  while read -r line; do
    echo $line
  done
  echo "loop terminated"
}

echo "about to invoke 'out'"
out < fifo
echo "at end of script"
```

To see the problem manifest, I am going to run three commands in three different terminals.  Each terminal session is represented by a column, and the vertical axis is global time:

```
Terminal 1              Terminal 2      Terminal 3
---------------         -------------   ----------------
$ ./trap-fifo1.sh
my PID: 42436
about to invoke 'out'
                        $ cat > fifo
in 'out'
                        hi
hi
                                        $ kill -s SIGUSR1 42436
in 'handler'
handler complete
loop terminated
at end of script
```

The loop stopped when we sent `SIGUSR1`.  That is because a pending `read` fails when a signal is received and handled.  (Aside: I struggled to find an authoritative reference for this empirically observed behavior.  The best I found is https://ss64.com/bash/trap.html but I don't know where that text comes from.  I could not find it in either [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) nor the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap).)

### How can we fix it?

The problem is the ambiguity in `read`, that we do not know if it fails because of `trap` or because of end of file.  So we will set a flag in `handler`.  Here is `trap-fifo2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "my PID: $$"

trap handler USR1

handler_invoked=false

handler() {
  echo "in 'handler'"
  echo caught_user1 > fifo
  handler_invoked=true
  echo "handler complete"
}

out() {
  echo "in 'out'"
  while true; do
    if read -r line; then
      echo $line
    elif $handler_invoked; then
      echo "flag set, continuing"
      handler_invoked=false
    else
      echo "flag unset, stopping"
      break
    fi
  done
  echo "after while loop"
}

echo "about to invoke 'out'"
out < fifo
echo "at end of script"
```

Now let's see the fix in action:

```
Terminal 1              Terminal 2      Terminal 3
---------------         -------------   ----------------
$ ./trap-fifo2.sh
my PID: 42562
about to invoke 'out'
                        $ cat > fifo
in 'out'
                        hello
hello
                                        $ kill -s SIGUSR1 42562
in 'handler'
handler complete
flag set, continuing
caught_user1

                        again
again
                                        $ kill -s SIGUSR1 42562
in 'handler'
handler complete
flag set, continuing
caught_user1
                        (Ctrl+D)
flag unset, stopping
after while loop
at end of script
```

From there we only need to adapt the original script by adding the flag and checking it in the loop, which should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

When the main process get SIGUSR1, it is in the middle of a read (inside function out). Few things will happen:
* The pending read is suspended
* The trap get activated (appending yo2 to the fifo)
* The read is resumed, and immediately fail with error code
* The while loop in out is terminated, and the script exit.

You might want to consider a different solution, where the 'out' method is background, and the 'main' script will only handle signal requests, while waiting for the child to finish

Replace the line ,out

```
out < $fifo &
# Loop forever. Add exit condition.
while true ; do wait ; done
```

Comment: I was trying to accomplish it within the script itself as I have already solved the problem by using another script to write into the FIFO thus keeping it open and not rewriting everything from scratch.

Comment: The code I suggested will be placed into the end the existing script.

Comment: btw, is there any way I can prevent the read from failing after the trap and keep the while loop running?